# Can the SQLite Database in Pocketbase be modified to your own liking?

Tags: database, sqlite, go, pocketbase

Pocketbase is cunrretly my BaaS solution and due to its flexability I can change/modify the code using Go. I was wondering if I can change the defualt SQLite database and change to something like a MongoDB/Redis database.

I have dug through the files and found nothing but yes/no answers and not a explaination.

Comment: sqlite "speaks" a dialect of SQL to provide relational data storage.  Redis and Mongo are very different.  So while it's probably possible to use Mongo / Redis instead, it would be a big ask to switch to not just a different SQL engine but a totally different database style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry mate not at this moment it seems.

Pocketbase states this at the of the [FAQ](https://pocketbase.io/faq#:%7E:text=6.%20Can%20I%20use%20database%20X%3F) page:

> **6. Can I use database X?**
>
> PocketBase uses embedded SQLite (in WAL mode) and there are no plans for supporting other databases.

Additionally, in this [issue](https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/issues/1631):

> Currently only SQLite is supported. Support for other SQL databases may be added in the future but for now it is a very low priority.

As for to why, here is the reason:

> The main reason for now to even consider adding support for other SQL databases is to support cloud providers with ephemeral storage, not because of scaling (there are other things beside the database that prevents PocketBase to scale horizontally and this is by design).
>
> There are no plans for Redis, since to maximize the performance, we rely heavily on the SQL syntax (even the API rules are converted to SQL statements).

Futher discussions [here](https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/discussions/14) and [here](https://github.com/pocketbase/pocketbase/discussions/1395).

Answer (score 0):

You can scale out SQLite and hence pocketbase using Marmot .

It’s on GitHub and runs as a binary on any server and is written in golang.

https://github.com/maxpert/marmot

Works very well

So you don’t have to change to a different db in order to scale out Pocketbase.

The load balancer , like caddy , will send requests to however many pocket base servers you running .

Each servers SQLite db will be automatically kept in sync by Marmot.

I use this and it’s been great and is very easy to use.

Let me know if that helps